# Countif conditional criteria

Tags: excel

I have a set of data with the max value for each col in the top row 
I want to count how many times each row has the highest value for the col

Right now im trying  =COUNTIF(B3:I3,"="&B$2)
but it keeps the value remains at B2 and always just checks if the value is 84

Is this possible with one simple line?

```
              A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
            Max 84  85  84  82  88  81  89  81
           wins
    bob      0  42  52  45  59  55  69  60  70
    joe      0  64  60  61  57  57  53  60  56
    ron      1  82  85  77  74  81  78  74  77
    fred     0  50  59  54  65  62  73  62  71
    jon      2  84  81  82  72  88  78  76  73
    evan     1  74  82  73  75  79  81  68  76
    alex     4  83  75  84  82  78  76  89  81
```

Comment: in which direction are you copying the formula? Down or to the right? What do you expect the formula to be after copying one cell?

Comment: Down, ill update my example I want to see how many time each person "won"

Comment: Also I count 4 for the last row. C,D,H and I

Comment: yup 4, this is why i need to use excel

Comment: Did you see my answer.  It is how I found the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUM(IF(B3:I3=$B$1:$I$1,1,0))
```

Put in A3.  It is an array formula, confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy down.

[image]

Comment: @LiamG You need to put the formula in A3, Then while still in edit mode, as in the cursor is in the formula bar, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: @LiamG I added a picture.  This is an Array formula, if you do the above it will have `{}` surrounding the formula.  Do not type these they get put in automatically when you hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 2):

As a non-array formula (complete with a regular Enter)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B4:I4=$B$2:$I$2))
```